# fullCalendar and dialog problem

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I've downloaded the fullCalendar package and included the jquery.js file and the calendar works, but when I try to open a jquery dialog, it won't open!

I've downloaded the jquery package from jquery.com and included the js from there instead.
Now the dialog works but not the calendar!

What am I doing wrong?

All the jquery files are at the same location.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

For those still looking for the answer to this question:

I had the same problem ("jquery is not defined") and it was because I was loading fullcalendar.js before jquery.js, like so...:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Changing the order and loading jquery.js first fixed the problem, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The FullCalendar package comes with jQuery v1.3.2, whereas the latest version of jQuery is 1.4.2. It also uses jQuery UI core, resizable and draggable v1.7.2 (not Modal), and the latest for these files would be 1.8.1.

So, I don't know which versions you are using, but I do know that FullCalendar works with jQuery v1.4.2 because it is working on one of my sites (I still have jQuery UI 1.7.2 running). So first off, check to make sure each plugin works with your files separately, then together.

Also, it would be a good idea to get the Firebug addon (Firebug lite for non-Firefox browsers) to show you if any errors are occurring.

Edit: You could just link to the Google API versions of jQuery/jQuery UI

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: i've checked it with firebug and i saw the next error:
"jquery is not defined" in the last row of my fullCalender.js file.

is this got something to do with name conventions ??

i'm using all the right version. the same as came with the fullCalender package

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the `$('#calendar').fullCalendar()` function inside of a document ready (`$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`) function?